# Facing errors in flutter when using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I am facing error in flutter when I use firebase. The app is not building. This is the error which I am facing:-

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:preDebugBuild`.

  > Android dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime' has different version for the compile (2.0.0-rc01) and runtime (2.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at [help gradle](https://help.gradle.org)

```
BUILD FAILED in 1m 44s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       108.0s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_core...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                            
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                   11.2s


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project `firebase_core`.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at [help gradle](https://help.gradle.org)

```
BUILD FAILED in 9s


The plugin firebase_core could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Here is my code in pubspec.yaml file:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_database: ^1.0.5
  firebase_core: 0.3.0
  firebase_storage: 2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+1
  url_launcher: ^4.1.0+1
```

Comment: Can you show your android/build.gradle file?

Comment: https://github.com/sharman13/firebasedatabse